# Can't seem to use use pandas to_csv and read_csv to properly read numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

The problem seems to stem from when I read in the csv with read_csv having a type issue when I try to perform operations on the nparray. The following is a minimum working example.

```
x = np.array([0.83151197,0.00444986])
df = pd.DataFrame({'numpy': [x]})
np.array(df['numpy']).mean()

Out[151]: array([ 0.83151197,  0.00444986])
```

Which is what I would expect. However, if I write the result to a file and then read the data back into a pandas DataFrame the types are broken.

```
x = np.array([0.83151197,0.00444986])
df = pd.DataFrame({'numpy': [x]})
df.to_csv('C:/temp/test5.csv')
df5 = pd.read_csv('C:/temp/test5.csv', dtype={'numpy': object})
np.array(df5['numpy']).mean()
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'long'

The following is the output of "df5" object

```
df5 
Out[186]:     
    Unnamed: 0                      numpy 
 0           0    [0.83151197  0.00444986]
```

The following is the file contents:

```
,numpy
0,[ 0.83151197  0.00444986]
```

The only way I have figured out how to get this to work is to read the data and manually convert the type, which seems silly and slow.

```
[float(num) for num in df5['numpy'][0][1:-1].split()]
```

Is there anyway to avoid the above?

Comment: `object` = No conversion. The types are all strings, basically.

Comment: You need eval convert object to list

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have used dtype as `dtype={'numpy': np.float64}` but get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: [ 0.83151197  0.00444986]`

Comment: show the file contents and df5 object.

Comment: @hpaulj added to original post so other people could see it.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.DataFrame({'col_name': data})` expects a 1D array alike objects as `data`:

```
In [63]: pd.DataFrame({'numpy': [0.83151197,0.00444986]})
Out[63]:
      numpy
0  0.831512
1  0.004450

In [64]: pd.DataFrame({'numpy': np.array([0.83151197,0.00444986])})
Out[64]:
      numpy
0  0.831512
1  0.004450
```

you've wrapped numpy array with `[]` so you passed a list of numpy arrays:

```
In [65]: pd.DataFrame({'numpy': [np.array([0.83151197,0.00444986])]})
Out[65]:
                      numpy
0  [0.83151197, 0.00444986]
```

Replace `df = pd.DataFrame({'numpy': [x]})` with `df = pd.DataFrame({'numpy': x})`

Demo:

```
In [56]: x = np.array([0.83151197,0.00444986])
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'numpy': x})
#                                   ^  ^
    ...: df.to_csv('d:/temp/test5.csv', index=False)
    ...:

In [57]: df5 = pd.read_csv('d:/temp/test5.csv')

In [58]: df5
Out[58]:
      numpy
0  0.831512
1  0.004450

In [59]: df5.dtypes
Out[59]:
numpy    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm actually needing the array. My data will end up being `file1, [value1,value2, value3, value3]
           file2, [value4,value4, valur5, value6]`. Doing it the way you suggested will make calculations more difficult down the road as I'll have to eventually do statistics over values of value1 and value4 (mean, stddev etc.), values2 and value4, value3 and value5 etc.

Comment: @KevinVasko, will __all__ your column contain lists or just some of them?

Comment: @KevinVasko, i wouldn't recommend you to store complex objects like lists, dicts, sets, etc. in Pandas cells - you will loose flexibility and most of vectorized functions will not work with such columns...

Comment: this is the only one that currently will contains an array.