# Why does pandas.DataFrame.mean() work but pandas.DataFrame.std() does not over same data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to figure out why the pandas.DataFrame.mean() function works over a ndarray of ndarrays, but the pandas.DataFrame.std() does not over the same data. The following is a minimum example.

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([4,5,6])
df = pd.DataFrame({"numpy": [x,y]})

df["numpy"].mean() #works as expected
Out[231]: array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5])

df["numpy"].std() #does not work as expected
Out[231]: TypeError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

However, if I do it through

```
df["numpy"].values.mean() #works as expected
Out[231]: array([ 2.5,  3.5,  4.5])

df["numpy"].values.std() #works as expected
Out[233]: array([ 1.5,  1.5,  1.5])
```

Debug information:

```
df["numpy"].dtype
Out[235]: dtype('O')

df["numpy"][0].dtype
Out[236]: dtype('int32')

df["numpy"].describe()
Out[237]: 
count             2
unique            2
top       [1, 2, 3]
freq              1
Name: numpy, dtype: object

df["numpy"]
Out[238]: 
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [4, 5, 6]
Name: numpy, dtype: object
```

Comment: I think i [warned you already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271238/cant-seem-to-use-use-pandas-to-csv-and-read-csv-to-properly-read-numpy-array#comment83526898_48271322) - you're going to have a lot of similar problems with non-scalar values in cells

Comment: Why are you using a DataFrame as a Dict? You should just load those values into DataFrame itself.

Comment: I agree with @MaxU. It seems a bit pointless to try answer this in the context of `pandas` builtin functions because this is fundamentally not how the library is supposed to be used. Creating a DataFrame just to drag values back out to arrays/lists... get rid of the middleman and leave pandas out of it - it's nothing but a hindrance if you choose to use it like this.

Comment: Why does it work with mean? Because of an implementation detail. By chance. This is in no way supported. You are just making your job harder by storing those arrays inside DataFrame cells.

Comment: @MaxU 1) I don't think I should see one function work but not the other though. To me that is just inconsistent and indicates some type of bug 2) This was the way the data was originally stored and it does make the most sense for this data. What do you suggest? Having 1.5 million columns all with 125 rows each? Or 125 (each index of the array), and 1.5 million rows? Logically it makes more sense to have 2 columns, one column containing the file name and the second containing the list of numbers with 1.5 million rows.

Comment: @KevinVasko, do all your subarrays are of the same shape?

Comment: @MaxU In this particular case yes. They are all 125 elements long.

Comment: @KevinVasko, in this case you could use 3D objects (for example [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html)), alternatively you can use multiindex - put your filename as an additional index level and having 125 columns

Comment: @roganjosh I have to calculate statistics based on the arrays (over the columns, rows etc.). So just use numpy and avoid using pandas at all? Is that your suggestion?

Comment: @KevinVasko it's only my suggestion in the current example case if you choose to store more than scalar values in a particular column. I would not do this myself. From what I understand from your comments, I would have 125 columns and 1.5 million rows. I'd possibly have another column with the file name that the data originated from (which would allow `groupby` at least). This setup would be intuitive to me in vanilla Excel too tbh if I was thinking outside of programming. I'm struggling to visualise it from your example.

Comment: @roganjosh the original post was just an example of what I was seeing. I have data in a file that lookes like.  

fileA, [1,2,3...125]
fileB, [1,2,3...125]

I will need to be doing calculations on rows or columns (e.g. average(col1 of all files) so in this case it would be average(1+1), average(2+2), ... average(125+125). Formatting is all messed up in comments but should describe the idea.

Comment: Yes, formatting is messed up so hopefully we're speaking the same language. You can still [average across rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33750326/compute-row-average-in-pandas) in addition to averaging columns. And if you had the originating file name as a column, you could use `groupby` to do it on a per-file basis, both in a row and column basis.

Comment: See [#17998](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17998) on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the following orginal DF (containing numpy arrays of the same shape in cells):

```
In [320]: df
Out[320]:
  file      numpy
0    x  [1, 2, 3]
1    y  [4, 5, 6]
```

Convert it to the following format:

```
In [321]: d = pd.DataFrame(df['numpy'].values.tolist(), index=df['file'])

In [322]: d
Out[322]:
      0  1  2
file
x     1  2  3
y     4  5  6
```

Now you are free to use all the Pandas/Numpy/Scipy power:

```
In [323]: d.sum(axis=1)
Out[323]:
file
x     6
y    15
dtype: int64

In [324]: d.sum(axis=0)
Out[324]:
0    5
1    7
2    9
dtype: int64

In [325]: d.mean(axis=0)
Out[325]:
0    2.5
1    3.5
2    4.5
dtype: float64

In [327]: d.std(axis=0)
Out[327]:
0    2.12132
1    2.12132
2    2.12132
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try instead of how I'm doing it currently.